# What are the terms for months with 30 days and for months with 31 days?

Tags: word-request

I would like to know if there are any terms to represent a month with 30 days or 31 days respectively.

Big month? Leap month?

Comment: A *leap month* is an extra [*intercalary*](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/intercalary) month inserted between two regular months.  Leap months do not occur in the Gregorian calendar, which is the calendar used in most English-speaking countries.

Comment: Do you mean, are there separate terms for 30-day months vs 31-day months? Or do you mean a term for non-February months?  If the former see [knuckles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_days_hath_September#Knuckles) entry

Comment: I found [this](http://www.jewishgen.org/infofiles/m_calint.htm), concerning the Jewish calendar: “A month of 30 days is called male ('full'), one of 29 days is chaser ('defective').” Also related, [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37586). I think it's safe to say that, if English _does_ have words for 30- and 31-day months, those words are rarely used and seldom heard.

Comment: I'm with @J.R.  My instinctive answer is that there is no such word, but of course I've nothing to back that up except never having heard it and being unable to google an answer!  (Very amused by 'defective' months, though. Interesting!)

Comment: @jwpat7 I mean the former one. 
J.R. Thanks for linking to that question.
Maybe I just use even month or odd month.

Comment: @Ivan: _Even_ or _odd_ would not be a good way to say it. As snailplane points out, most people would consider the "even" months to be Feb, Apr, Jun, Aug, Oct, and Dec – two of those months have 30 days, and three of them have 31, thanks to the consecutive 31-day months of July and August. You could use _full_ and _short_, but I'd probably be inclined to go with "31-day_month" to keep ambiguity at a minimum.

Comment: @J.R. That's true. Everyone understand "30-day months" so I will use that instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want separate terms to refer to 30-day months and 31-day months, I doubt you'll do better than *30-day months* and *31-day months*.

*Even* and *odd* sound nice, but they have an unfortunate flaw: people use them to refer to even- and odd-numbered months!  That is, months 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and 11 are odd; months 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and 12 are even.

The term *knuckle month* sounds nice, too, but not everyone will get the reference, I'm afraid.  I'm certain of this because I just talked to a friend a couple weeks ago who was unfamiliar with the knuckle mnemonic.

You can, of course, use a term like *knuckle month* or *odd month*, as long as you're careful to tell people what you mean by it.  But if your goal is to communicate without further explanation, I would avoid looking for special terms like these (fun as it may be) and simply state the number of days.

Comment: In Hong Kong, I believe most of the people know the idea of knuckles mnemonic. Though people may not recognise meaning of the term "knuckle month" immediately.

Comment: Thirty days hath September  
April, June, and November  
All the rest have thirty-one  
But February's twenty-eight  
The LEAP YEAR, which comes once in four  
Gives February one day more  
  
Useful? Probably not, but when else will I get to use that rhyme?
*edit* this would look better if I could get line breaks to work

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but it might be useful to know. At my former employer, we called them *standard* and *extended* (as in *standard-length month* and *extended-by-one-day month*). February was referred to as *leap* or *extended leap*, depending on the year.

The March and October were sometimes referred to as *increased* and *decreased* because of the one-hour offset when the daylight saving kicks in and out.

So there was expressions like *accumulated work hours in the extended and non-decreased months*. Not surprisingly, the nomenclature was as painful as it was precise.